# Android stop Service using (Pending) Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-notifications

I have the method

```
    private Notification getNotification() {

    Activity currentActivity = MyApplication.getApplication().getCurrentActivity();
    Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity, SpeechActivationService.class);
    i.putExtra(ACTIVATION_STOP_INTENT_KEY, true);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(currentActivity, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_mic_off, "Deactivate", resultPendingIntent);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_mic)
        .setTicker("TickerSample")
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setContentTitle("My App Voice Control")
        .setContentText("Voice Control is Activated")
        .addAction(action)
        .build();

    return notification;
}
```

It is supposed to make a notification which stays active for as long as the service is active. The notification has a DEACTIVATE Button, which can send an Intent, wrapped in a Pending Intent (whatever the difference is?!). It seems Intents are the only form of Action a notification can take for handling Button clicks, so I can't just do

```
stopService(new Intent(this, SpeechActivationService.class));
```

on that DEACTIVATE. But with my code onStartCommand() in SpeechActivationService never gets called when I click on DEACTIVATE. And Services don't inherit an onNewIntent() method. So what method gets called when I send this intent by pressing DEACTIVATE?

Comment: You wan to stop a service by pressing a button in the service? Is that button supposed to do any other task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what method gets called when I send this intent by pressing DEACTIVATE?

Nothing will. You are attempting to use a `getActivity()` `PendingIntent` with an `Intent` that points to a service. This will not work, and you should be getting messages in LogCat to that effect.

If you change `getActivity()` to `getService()`, then `onStartCommand()` of your service should be called.

Answer (score 1):

Pending intents is ment to be used for controlling stuff outide of your app (system features use those). For stopping service create BroadcastReceiver, which will receive pending intent (PendingIntent.getBroadcast()), which, in turn, will stop your Service

Comment: Thank you, now I know what PendingIntents are for. But it seems they also call classes which don't register as BroadcastReceiver, because with the small fix from CommonsWare answer, onStartCommand() in my Service gets called now too.